# Adding p-values to jitter plot altere the structure of the facet and doesn't show the data properlly

Tags: r

I have a df with the following column names:

```
[1] "Sample_ID"                           "group_classification"               
[3] "Days_after_infection_1"              "category post-infection or 1st dose"
[5] "p.i. category#"                      "category post-1st dose"             
[7] "post 1st dose category#"             "category post-2nd dose"             
[9] "post 2nd dose category#"             "abs"                                
[11] "titers"                              "control_classification"             
[13] "log_titers"
```

I'm using this code to plot a facet:

```
ggboxplot(test1,
          x = "group_classification",
          y = "log_titers",
          facet.by = "abs",
          ylab = "Ab Titer (AU/ml)",
          xlab = "group_classification",
          add = "jitter") +
  #scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.005, 0.005))) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = NULL), 
         shape = guide_legend(title = NULL))
```

This is the result:
[image]

When I want to add the p-values from a Dunn test (using another df), the structure of my plot becomes unreadable, because the p-values use all the space in each panel and I y-axis changes the range, adding this line:

```
stat_pvalue_manual(df.dunn.stat, 
                     step.increase = 0.1, 
                     hide.ns = 'p',
                     label = 'p.adj.signif')
```

My plots become in this:
[image]

My dunn df looks like this:

```
abs            .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic       p   p.adj p.adj.signif y.position groups
  <chr>          <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <name>
1 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Contr… Induc…    10    14     3.04  2.36e-3 7.08e-3 **              920138. <chr> 
2 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Contr… Natur…    10    38     3.34  8.43e-4 3.37e-3 **             1038104. <chr> 
3 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Contr… Hybrid    10    27     5.65  1.60e-8 9.58e-8 ****           1156071. <chr> 
4 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Induc… Natur…    14    38    -0.232 8.16e-1 8.16e-1 ns             1274037. <chr> 
5 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Induc… Hybrid    14    27     2.53  1.15e-2 2.29e-2 *              1392003. <chr> 
6 SARS_COV1_Spi… tite… Natur… Hybrid    38    27     3.60  3.22e-4 1.61e-3 **             1509970. <chr>
```

What can I do to add the significance without change y-axis in my face?

Comment: Fix your `y.position` values. They are obviously way too high.

Comment: I do not understand. I think that I need to put this in ```stat_pvalue_manual```, however, why do the points get to the bottom? if the argument is for the ```p-values```, any comment is welcome

Comment: Your first plot shows a y-scale from 0 to 6. Your „dunn df“ contains y.position values in the millions. By default stat_pvalue_manual is using these for the positioning. You can either fix them in the data.frame or pass different values to the stat.